# Binding F1 to ESC in VIM

Tags: vim, linux-mint

Evening,

I got a Lenovo T400 laptop, and the F1 is in a stupid place, and keep hitting it instead of hitting Esc to get change modes with VIM.

I did some googling, and tried adding

```
map <F1> <Esc>
imap <F1> <Esc>
```

to my ~/.vimrc file, but to no avail...

If I can't do this with a vimrc, is there a way to change it at the linux/system level?

Using Linux Mint 14 MATE

--

Answer:
The terminal application has it's on keyboard shortcuts defined. Under Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts you can disable the help. Then the map/imap above will work fine.

You can also edit the keyboard settings in the main system keyboard preferences. Open that up and go to Layouts -> Options and play with the Caps Lock key behaviour. You can disable it, or even bind it to ESC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be that your keyboard isn't producing the keycode that Vim translates to `<F1>`. In Vim, go into insert mode, and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. Then press <kbd>F1</kbd>. The string that you just inserted is the string that needs to go on the left-hand side of your `map` command. It might be `<x-F1>` or something similar. You can do this to insert the key name directly in your `.vimrc` file.

Remember to restart Vim after editing your `.vimrc` file.

Regardless of whether you get this working, you might like to swap your <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys, which is quite a popular thing to do among Vim users. You can't do that within Vim, you need to edit your X configuration to achieve it. [The Vim tips wiki tells you how](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows).

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `Ctrl-c`. I know alot of people don't like to combine `Ctrl-*`, btu for me it feels natural after years of horrible binds in WoW.

Comment: Thanks, however when I do Ctrl-V and Press F1, FireFox still opens and goes to linuxmint.com/documentation page. So I don't get to see the value. Any other ideas? Checking the 'Keyboard Shortcuts' in the mint preferences doesn't show a F1 keyboard shortcut

Comment: Thanks, this helped me sort it out, the main issue was due to the keyboard shortcuts defined in the terminal app. Once removed I could then check what the F1 key was etc. Thanks!